# Webpack build for svg and images in CSS files

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My entry for CSS is

```
'style': './app'
```

Now I have two folders `images` and `svg`, and the css files in the app/style.css uses the path for `.svg` and `.png, jpg`, from these two folders. How can I configure `webpack` with appropriate loaders so that images and svgs will remain static.
Also the build fails if any of the svg is missing. Is there any way to ignore the errors and complete the build.

I am using `webpack --inline --progress` and `rimraf prod && webpack --config --progress --profile --bail` for build.